# NetBeans project compiled with one or more errors

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I've been trying to Run a simple program on NetBeans but just after I hit the RUN, I get a Message Box with- One or more projects were compiled with errors.Application may end unexpectedly. 
When I "Run is anyway" I get the desired output for the program but if I cancel it, I get this error on the Output pane-

> run: /root/.netbeans/6.8/var/cache/executor-snippets/run.xml:45: 
>   Cancelled by user

When I click on the error, I'm taken to

```
        <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
```

line on a run.xml file.

My code is:

```
public class minitest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connect conn=null;
         try{
        Domain testDomain=conn.domainLookupByName("test");
        System.out.println("Domain:" + testDomain.getName() + " id " +
                           testDomain.getID() + " running " 
                           );
        } catch (LibvirtException e){
        System.out.println("exception caught:"+e);
        System.out.println(e.getError());
        }
        }
        } }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you don't have all project required libraries in the classpath ...

Have you verified the classpath ? For example you use libvirt, do you have libvirt jar in your project classpath ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the run.xml file 
You can open this file by just clicking the link 
Code:

```
C:\Users\Nenad\.netbeans\7.0\var\cache\executor-snippets\run.xml
```

in run window.

Then set `dir = ""`

so that part looks like this:

```
  <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${classname}" dir="" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true">
```